# tox don't read setup.cfg

Tags: python, setup.py, tox

I'm new to python and have some problems with tox.

My `tox.ini`

```
[tox]
envlist = py36

[testenv]
passenv = TOXENV CI TRAVIS TRAVIS_*
usedevelop = True
install_command = pip install -U {opts} {packages}
deps = -r{toxinidir}/test-requirements.txt
    -r{toxinidir}/requirements.txt
commands =
python -V
py.test -vvv -s

[testenv:docs]
commands =
python setup.py build_sphinx
```

My `setup.cfg`

```
[build_sphinx]
source-dir = docs/source
build-dir = docs/build
all_files = 1

[upload_sphinx]
upload-dir = docs/build/html
```

`python setup.py build_sphinx` works just fine, but `/Users/ben/development/python/test/.tox/docs/bin/python setup.py build_sphinx` says

> error: invalid command 'build_sphinx'

My environment

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.0

$ /Users/ben/development/python/test/.tox/docs/bin/python --version
Python 3.6.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install `sphinx` as part of your dependencies in order to use the `build_sphinx` setuptools/distutils command.

For instance:

```
[testenv:docs]
deps =
    # you may also need {[testenv]deps} here if you depend on the
    # parent deps
    sphinx
commands =
python setup.py build_sphinx
```

Comment: I added it to my `test-requirements.txt` and it worked, thank you